# Use Non Persistent field in Generic Inquiry Conditions

Tags: acumatica

I am building a Generic Inquiry which would list the Contract Details with FixedRecurringPriceVal and UsrCustomFixedRecurringPriceVal. The later is a custom persistent field. Now, in this Generic Inquiry I would like to list only those Contract Details from Customer Contract which have different FixedRecurringPriceVal and UsrCustomFixedRecurringPriceVal.

But, those I can use FixedRecurringPriceVal in Results Grid, it appears that I can't use this field in Condition where I needed to compare between these fields.

Upon looking at Data field source I find this.

```
        [PXDecimal(6)]
        [PXFormula(typeof(GetItemPriceValue<
            ContractDetail.contractID, 
            ContractDetail.contractItemID, 
            ContractDetailType.ContractDetail, 
            ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPriceOption, 
            Selector<ContractDetail.contractItemID, ContractItem.recurringItemID>, 
            ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPrice, 
            ContractDetail.basePriceVal,
            ContractDetail.qty,
            Switch<
                Case<Where<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.draft>,
                    Or<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.pendingActivation>>>,
                    IsNull<Parent<Contract.activationDate>, Parent<Contract.startDate>>,
                Case<Where<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.active>,
                    Or<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.inUpgrade>>>,
                    IsNull<Parent<ContractBillingSchedule.nextDate>, Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>>, 
                Case<Where<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.expired>>, 
                    IsNull<Parent<ContractBillingSchedule.nextDate>, Parent<Contract.expireDate>>,
                Case<Where<Parent<Contract.status>, Equal<Contract.status.canceled>>,
                    IsNull<Parent<Contract.terminationDate>, Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>>>>>>,
                Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>>>))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Recurring Price")]
        public decimal? FixedRecurringPriceVal
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

So, for me it looks like Non Persistent field can't be used in Generic Inquiry Conditions. I did a bit of google but couldn't find any solution and also looked at the S130 Data Retrieval and Analysis and couldn't find specific to such case.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use Non Persistent fields in the Conditions.
The field dropdown is intentionally excluding them. Below is the FieldSelecting event handler from the GenericInquiryDesigner graph which is loading the dropdown.

```
    protected void GIWhere_DataFieldName_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] allParameters = this.GetAllParameters(true);
        PXStringListAttribute.SetList(cache, e.Row, typeof(GIWhere.dataFieldName).Name, allParameters, allParameters);
        this.a<GIWhere.dataFieldName>(cache, e.Row, true, (PXCache c, string f) => !PXGenericInqGrph.IsVirtualField(c, f, null));
    }
```

The only way, in this case, will be to create a separate page instead of GI.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, not sure if I have missed this in the documentation.